# How do I find the complex eigenvectors of the given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to find the eigenvectors corresponding to the complex eigenvectors of the following matrix $$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -2 \end{pmatrix}  $$

I find the eigenvalues as $\lambda_1=-2, \lambda_2=1+2i$ and $ \overline{\lambda_2}=1-2i.$ For $\lambda_2 $, let us say $(A-\lambda_2I)\omega = 0$ so that
$$  \left( \begin{matrix} -1-2i & -2 & 0 \\ 1 & 1-2i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -2 \end{matrix} \right)\left( \begin{matrix} \omega_1  \\ \omega_2 \\ \omega_3 \end{matrix} \right) = 0.$$
Therefore I obtain the equations

- $(-1-2i)\omega_1 -2\omega_2 = 0$
- $\omega_1 +(1-2i)\omega_2 =0$
- $(-2)\omega_3= 0$

Now, we have $\omega_3= 0$. Using the second equation we get $\omega_1=(2i-1)\omega_2$ and substituting into the first equation, I get $$-(1+2i)(-1+2i)\omega_2-2\omega_2 =0\implies 3\omega_2=0 \implies \omega_2=0.$$
Thus,  I obtain $\omega_1=0$ and in the end we get $\omega=(0,0,0)$. However, it must be non-zero. What do I do wrong or is there any better/easier way to find the desired eigenvectors?

Comment: Are you sure about your eigenvalues? I think they are $1\pm i,\,-2$. The Characteristic eqution is $(x+2)(x^2-2x+2)$, whos solutions are what i wrote.

Comment: You are right, my bad. After correcting the equation I obtain $\omega_2 - \omega_2 = 0$ at some part. Then is it okay to set $\omega_2 = 1$ so  that in the end I get $\omega_1 =(-1+i)$?